# Javascript and Mobile get base URL on phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, browser

I need a way to get the base URL of a webpage and it has to be comparable with just all new phones (android, windows, apple)

`window.location.assign(window.location.origin + '/test.aspx');` will return different results on different phones. so will `window.location.reload(window.location.origin + '/test.aspx');`

I need to get the base url of the webpage + the folder above it. For example:

`www.test.com/foo.aspx`

needs to become `www.test.com/test.aspx`

Ideas?

Comment: What are the inconsistencies you've experienced with `window.location.origin`? Is `window.location.href` more consistent? Maybe you could parse the origin out of that.

Comment: I found a workaround, but in IE (windows phones) `window.location.origin` returns `undefined`